# How can I save a Item color from a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView with person names. When I clicked a name I change the color of name clicked. but when I create the activity again, I lose the item colors. Anyone can help me?

obs: I'm using a simple ArrayAdapter for my listView.

Comment: why not save the color in a `Map` using the color and list position and save that `Map` to `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Do you have same example about it? because using just sharedPreferences I didn't get it!

Comment: you are using the View to hold a value of the Model. You need to start by moving the notion of an item being selected in your item model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of onSaveInstance() try out this.

```
View lastTouchedView;

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
lastTouchedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
lastTouchedView = v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity or Fragment you can override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. In `onSaveInstanceState` you will be passed a bundle which you can use to save the color value. Then in `onRestoreInstanceState` you will be passed the bundle that contains the color value. Retrieve the color value and set it as the color.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // color values are usually int, but there are many other put methods
    // for a bundle so if the color is in a different form there are
    // other options
    outState.putInt("color", theColorValue);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set the name color using savedInstanceState.getInt("color");
}
```

As suggested by @inner_class7 you can also use `SharedPreferences` by calling `getSharedPreferences("someName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html for more info on how to use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here was a quick throw together of what you should do if its just selection... This is meant to be very simple in explaining how to make it work for you

I have created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/lt-tibs1984/45b390e1a8f1d91ffaaf)

This shows:

1. Use of a Simple model with some Text, and a selected boolean
2. Selecting and item to change its background, and preserve that on scroll
3. saving off the selected position of the elements using `SharedPreferences`
4. Using the `BaseAdapter` class for custom row items